# Laptop buying suggestions

Tags: laptop, processor, windows

I recently secured a job as a technical writer (proposal development) in an IT firm. The company will be providing a laptop when I am in the office, but for remote work, I will need my own Laptop. I am buying a Laptop after a decade so I am willing to spend up to 1000$. I am a Windows user, not a gamer but would like my Laptop to handle programs like Solidworks, Staad, Revit, Ansys, Matlab, etc, since I have a Mechanical Engineering background. I will mostly be using these programs as a hobbyist but may do some freelance design work. Ideally, I would want 11th generation i5 or its AMD equivalent, dedicated graphics card and 16 GB RAM. However, 8GB RAM is also acceptable,  if  future upgrade is possible. SSD of 256 GB is fine, battery life of 5 hrs would be good, but 3 hrs is also acceptable. I don't care much for weight & aesthetics. I really dig a 2-in-1 type of Laptop, but do realize that they generally come with the soldered Ram.

I looked at some options (Lenovo P series, ThinkPad, etc) but mostly these are mobile workstation types and go over my budget. Is my budget too tight for the requirements & specs I have mentioned? I would really appreciate your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 laptops that meet or almost meet your requirements:

The [MSI Gaming GF65 10UE-405NL](https://nl.hardware.info/laptops.18/msi-gaming-gf65-10ue-405nl.609852) has a 10th gen Intel core i5 and an RTX 3060. It has 16GB of RAM, expandable till 64GB, has a 512GB SSD and is probably going to handle 2.5-5 hours of work without charging.

The  [Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6](https://nl.hardware.info/laptops.18/lenovo-ideapad-5-pro-16ach6-82l5006pmh.604733) on the other hand, does feature a newer CPU (Ryzen 5 5600H), but has a GPU a little worse than the MSI (RTX 3050). All other specs are really similar though, except a better screen on the Lenovo and a bigger battery (probably a day of light work or close).

The links are to a Dutch revieuw and hardware news site (sorry Andy and ArtOfCode), and the laptops cost €999 in Belgium.

Comment: Appreciate your response, will look into them.